# Convert timezones in MySQL without access to timezones table

Tags: mysql, timezone

What I'm trying to do is to convert certain timestamps into the local time of the user. 
So what I would do is to ask the user about his timezone (select all the timezones from the corresponding table and then let user select from the list) and then

SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2004-01-01 12:00:00','UTC','MET')

Now the problem. I do not have access to the MySQL timezone tables (command denied to user '' for table 'time_zone' - probably the hosting doesn't allow me). So while I can execute commands as above, I cannot fetch all the timezone names that MySQL knows.

The reason why I want to use timezone names and not the offsets is to do not worry about things like daylight savings time.

So how can I circumvent this problem? I was looking for SQL request to create a duplicate of the table with timezone names but found only the one with GMT offsets, which doesn't work for me, as explained above.

Comment: MySQL uses regular [IANA time zone identifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).  Are you writing an application of some kind? Likely your application framework also uses these same identifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this link [timezonedb.com](https://timezonedb.com/download) where it is possible to download sql tables for the timezones. There is a small drawback of that sql - the table countries doesn't have a numerical index, but this is easy to fix. 
Thanks Matt Johnson for the hint!